# is this binary tree function postorder or preorder?

Tags: c++, binary-tree, tree-traversal

My understanding is that in binary tree, the preorder traversal visits the root node first, then traverses the left subtree, and finally traverses the right subtree. The postorder traversal visits the left subtree, then the right subtree, and finally the root node.

In the final of my class this asks if this the function `f()` is preorder or postorder.

```cpp
template 
int f(treeNode* t)
{
   int n=0, leftValue, rightValue;
   if (t != NULL) {
      if (t->leftChild != NULL || t->rightChild != NULL)
         n++;
      leftValue = f(t->leftChild);
      rightValue = f(t->rightChild);
      return n + leftValue + rightValue;
   } else
      return 0;
}
```

Doesn't this travel the down the left tree, the the right tree before processing anything? So it should be postorder shouldn't it?

Similar to how this function to delete the nodes in a binary tree:

```cpp
clear(Node* curr) {
   if (!curr)
      return;

   clear(curr->left);
   clear(curr->right);
   delete curr;
}
```

Comment: "Pre" mean *before*, and "post" means *after*. Basically "preorder" means that you process the node data *before* you traverse its children. And "postorder" means you process the node data *after* you have traversed the children.

Comment: In this case, `n` is incremented before traversing children. But data is processed after traversal when `return n + leftValue + rightValue` is called right?

Comment: The result of `f` doesn't depend on the traversal order, so the question is rather meaningless.

Comment: Pre- and post- orders are _sequences of node values_.   A traversal can generate a pre- or post-order, but none of the code you show does that. The question is silly. Your teacher blew it.

Comment: Can you tell him that and get my points back? lol

Comment: Once had an instructor who noted the ten-or-so students still writing the exam a good half hour after everyone else had left, looked over the exam, and said, "If you're still working on the last question, just stop and go home. I screwed up."